# Spring mvc requested resource is not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Application and my browser cannot render any resource of my app. I saw a lot of similar questions and could not find any solution. App works fine through json(ie without view)

There  is my config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ru.practice.web")
public class ChatlocalWebConfig
extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 @Bean
 public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
   InternalResourceViewResolver resolv = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   resolv.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
   resolv.setSuffix(".jsp");
   resolv.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
   return resolv;
   }

}
```

initializer

```
public class ChatlocalInitializer
extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
  return new String[] { "/" };
}


@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
return new Class<?>[] { ChatlocalWebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
return new Class<?>[] { ChatlocalWebConfig.class };
} 
}
```

controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
 @Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHello(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");
return "welcome";
}
}
```

and project structure
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VylOW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your resource path problem. Change

`resolv.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");`

to `resolv.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");`

and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but this works:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver r = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        r.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        r.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```